# Bad request при отправке формы

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

Есть такая проблема: пишу мини-приложение с помощью flask-а и получаю ошибку bad request. Как это исправить? Вот отрывок кода:

```
@app.route('/', methods = ['POST', 'GET'])
def hello():
    return render_template('hello.html')

@app.route('/start', methods = ['POST', 'GET'])
def start():
    Slogin = request.form['login']
    Spasswd = request.form['passwd']
    auto_send_30(check_auth(Slogin, Spasswd), posl1, posl2, Slogin, Spasswd)
    return render_template('good.html')
```

Я абсолютно уверен в том, что функции auto_send_30 и check_auth работают на 100% верно. И вот привожу код hello.html:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
      <h2>Test</h2>

        <input type="text" name = 'login' required>
        <input type="text" name = 'passwd' required>
      <form action = '/start'><p><input value='Запустить шарманку' type='SUBMIT'></p></form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Подозреваю, что `<input>` вне `<form>` не обработались. Проверьте, что Вам в `request` возвращается.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Передаваемые поля должны быть внутри общего тега `<form>`
2. По умолчанию (если в теге `<form>` не указан параметр `method`) данные передаются методом `GET` (внутри url запроса), и попадают в `request.args`. Чтобы данные попадали в `request.form`, нужно передавать методом `POST`, для этого указать `<form action = '/start' method='post'>`. Критичные данные (такие как данные авторизации) лучше передавать именно через `POST`.

Пример шаблона:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
      <h2>Test</h2>
      <form action = '/start' method='post'>
        <input type="text" name = 'login' required>
        <input type="text" name = 'passwd' required>
        <p><input value='Запустить шарманку' type='SUBMIT'></p>
      </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

В коде для `/start` оставляете только обработку метода POST:

```
@app.route('/start', methods = ['POST'])
def start():
    Slogin = request.form['login']
    Spasswd = request.form['passwd']
    auto_send_30(check_auth(Slogin, Spasswd), posl1, posl2, Slogin, Spasswd)
    return render_template('good.html')
```